# Error: resource not found ({} ) when running travis cli command

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I am getting this message whenever I try to run a travis command.
This is the minimal reproducible example:

```
$ travis version
1.11.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]
$ travis status
resource not found ({}
)
```

I am on macOS Ventura / Apple Silicon

I have tried different rub versions, reinstalled the Travis CLI, no success.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. Using --pro raises an error because my account is only for public domain so I tried with --org and with that argument, the error is the same "resource not found ({})" there is something definitively wrong at travis side!

Comment: I suggest you reach out to Travis support. They were quick to respond. They should at least improve their error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reaching out to travis support I got the suggestion to first log in using the travis cli like this:

```
travis login --pro --github-token GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Where GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN can be found on GitHub under:
Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens

I could then perform my travis cli tasks without further errors.

While this solved my problem, I still consider this behaviour of the travis CLI a bug.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I was able to find a fix for it by adding `--pro` flag to the CLI commands as specified here https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/